# Execution failed for task ':app:nodeSetup', Could not resolve org.nodejs:node:6.7.0 while adding plugin 'com.amazonaws.appsync'

Tags: android, node.js, amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-appsync

I am trying to use AWS AppSync in my android app but while setting up the things, I am getting the error

> **Could not resolve org.nodejs:node:6.7.0**

along with this comment

> Execution failed for task ':app:nodeSetup'.
>
> > Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'ivy' was added by unknown code

I have added a screenshot of error please refer to that if not getting the description.
[image]
It is coming mainly while I am adding the gradle plugin **com.amazonaws.appsync**.

Followed the steps given by the official aws [website](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/api/graphql/q/platform/android/#import-sdk-and-config).

**I have tried this [solution](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android/issues/377) but not working.** **Getting same error with different node version.**
Please let me know if any one faced the same and solved the issue.
Thanks and Happy Coding.

For reference adding my app gralde, project gradle and settings gralde files below, please have a look.

App build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.awsappsyncdemo'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.awsappsyncdemo"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
//    node {
//        version = "16.14.2"
//    } //solution not working so commented
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // AWS dependencies
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:3.3.1'
}
```

Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "AwsAppSyncDemo"
include ':app'
```